# Allow greek characters in Django usernames

Tags: python, regex, django

I would like to allow my users to register using greek characters.

I added in my admin.py file the following code. Is the regular expression correct ( `regex=r'^[\w\p{Greek}-]+$',`) ? I would like to allow greek and english characters

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  username = forms.RegexField(
    label='Username',
    max_length=30,
    regex=r'^[\w\p{Greek}-]+$',
    help_text = 'Required. 30 characters or fewer. Alphanumeric characters only (letters, digits, hyphens and underscores).',
    error_message = 'This value must contain only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores.')

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
  username = forms.RegexField(
    label='Username',
    max_length=30,
    regex=r'^[\w\p{Greek}-]+$',
    help_text = 'Required. 30 characters or fewer. Alphanumeric characters only (letters, digits, hyphens and underscores).',
    error_message = 'This value must contain only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores.')

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
  form = MyUserChangeForm
  add_form = MyUserCreationForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Yes. Just found the solution but I think it is not correct but it is working!

Comment: Do you have any problems, didn't that work for you or what ?

Comment: Did you try just using greek letters without configuring anything? Django is really good with language support, I use hebrew characters in my admin site without setting up anything and it works like a charm